# How do I remove this white space from the bottom of my page when I print?

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

I have a picture that I want to run to the bottom of the page edge. I've put the bottom margin to 0 and in the document view it appears at the bottom of the page. However, when in print preview and when actually printed there is a white space. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: The printer will adjust automatically the margins

Answer (score 3):

It is most likely coming from the printer you are printing to.  Most copiers/printers put 1-5mm of void area around the entire document.  This is intentional, to prevent jamming mainly, but other potential issues as well.  I believe the term here for what you are looking for, is called "full bleed".

Usually this is an option in the driver for color printers/copiers (depending on make/model), so your mileage may vary here.

Answer (score 0):

@RMarkwald's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1205400/213131) gives the most likely reason. However, another possibility is that the aspect ratio of the photo does not match that of the paper.

Most photos have a 3 x 2 aspect ratio. My camera has 24 million pixels, or 6000 x 4000. A standard print is 6" x 4" print. In both cases the ratio is 6/4 = 3/2.

Paper does not have that aspect ratio. For example, an A4 page is 210 mm x 297 mm, an aspect ration of 3 x 2.1212. Thus, the only way to fit a photo on this paper is to either distort the photo by squashing it vertically, or by cropping part of the photo. As the application will not do that, it cannot fill the paper. Hence the margins.

Comment: Another possibility as well, good call!